# Real time Tracker on Samrtphone using Bing Map

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I have read up on GPS Real time tracking and found out several things about it,mostly requiring PHP,but I need use only JavaScript.
As regards to my question, is it possible to do so with just html and JS, using markers or anything else to populate the Bing Map when you move anywhere in the city? Need some help on this, Thanks!
PS: I try to use it on WP8.1, and I am already succeed to add Bing map to it using html5
[My solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790300/map-apis-for-windows-phone-8-1-in-html-css-js/24839652#24839652)

and if there is a solution on Win8.1, it's Ok, just how do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In HTML5 you can use the geolocation class: http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_geolocation.asp or since you are using Bing Maps you can use the GeoLocationProvider class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh125833.aspx

Make sure you enable share of locations in your app manifest or it will silently fail to get the users location.

This would work in both WP8.1 and Win8.1, and browsers as well.

If you want you can also do all of this in a universal app using .NET.

Comment: I know about that, but the problem here how to draw the routes and show my path on map

Comment: by the way I work with HTML cause I need to implement the code with different platforms :)

Comment: Start off with your initial point and create a polyline that has that coordinate for the start and end. 

You can use the setInterval method in JavaScript to request the users location every few minutes. You can then check to see if the location has moved significantly or not, and if it has then add the point to the polyline.

Comment: I think that my next step will be :D