# My Windows App built with Cordova in VS 2015 is not working in bing map function page ( maybe there is no internet access )

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, winjs

I am developing Windows App using Cordova project template in Visual studio 2015.
However I've already succeeded all other versions IOS, Android, Windows Phone 8.

But I have much problems in Windows version.

UI is working correctly when I build it as Windows app. but it seems network is not working correctly.
My app has a page which is using bing map.
But when I visit this page, it can't load map at all. timed out. even my pc is available to connect internet.
I've tested app in local machine.

All network functions are messed up for windows version.

Anybody experienced this before?
Anybody can advice me about this major problem?

Best.

Comment: please have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061829/map-apis-not-working-for-windows-phone-in-html